# How can I check if only 1 element of a certain class remains, and if so perform an action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a link with the class .deleteLink I'd like to be able to know when only 1 of this elements remain and when that happens hide that anchor. I don't think I have a good idea of how to do this though so far this is what I've got:

```
$('.deleteLink').click(function(){
   var $deletes = $('.deleteLink');
   $deletes.each(function(index){
       alert(index + " : " + $(this).attr('class'));
   });
});
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to say that those links are being created via another anchor (#addLink) so I had trouble to get ahold of them until I changed the code to :

```
$('.deleteLink').live('click', function(){
```

still when I want to hide or remove the last .deleteLink nothing is affected.

Comment: you'd better show your html stucture.i dont know what you wanna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.deleteLink').click(function(){
 var $deletes = $('.deleteLink').length;
 if ($deletes == 1){
     $(".deleteLink").hide();
 }
```

});

Answer (score 1):

When you will have only one link condition below will be `true`:

```
$deletes.length == 1
```